# How to Nesting React Components with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to map 4 separate components into their respective rows using JSON data.

You can see the app here -  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kt1zf8

#### Data.json

```
const data = {

    "lanes":[
        {
            "_uid": "001",
            "name": "Lane1",
            "type": "Toll",
                "cars":[
                  {
                      "component": "Bmw",
                      "name": "i8",
                      "number": "12345",
                  },
                  {
                      "component": "Lambo",
                      "name": "Aventador",
                      "number": "214512512",
        
                  },
            ]
        },
          {
            "_uid": "002",
            "name": "Lane2",
            "type": "Easy Pay",
                "cars":[
                  {
                      "component": "Fiat",
                      "name": "i8",
                      "number": "12345",
                  },
                  {
                      "component": "Dodge",
                      "name": "Aventador",
                      "number": "214512512",
        
                  },
            ]
        },
    ]
}

export default data
```

The Rows are rendered in their own component using the "uid" key from JSON.

Mapping the row data (Lanes & Car Type) is rendering correctly. In the stack blitz, you can see the data in each row is unique.

However, when I try to map the nested data, only the results of the first lane is returning on both rows.

[image: Lanes]

In the **Components.jsx**, I am using the unique id ("uid") key of the lanes in **data.js** to determine the lanes but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Why are only the first two results showing when they are using the same key?

Comment: you are doing wrong. check your carcontainer.js

Comment: Because you are only looping through one lane everytime using `data.lanes[0]` code: `{data.lanes[0].cars.map(block => Components(block))}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

CarContainer

```
const CarContainer = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className="car-container">
        {props.data.cars.map(block => Components(block))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarContainer;
```

LaneInfo

```
const LaneInfo = () => {
  const [laneData, setLaneData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLaneData(data.lanes);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {laneData &&
        laneData.map((p) => (
          <>
            <div className="lane">
              <div className="space" key={p.uid}>
                <div>{p.name}</div>
                <div>{p.type}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <CarContainer data={p}/>
          </>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
export default LaneInfo;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm now just learning hooks, so I forgot all about passing props.